# Visual Studio 2008 freezing when editing aspx/master pages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio freezes up continually when I'm editing master pages or aspx files. Here's what I've tried that have not helped:

- restarting VS
- only working with few files open at a time
- Disabled all addins (resharper etc.)
- deleted .suo and .user files
- changed default editor
  from Web Form Editor and Master Page
  Editor to HTML Editor
- installed SP1

I don't have tons of files - 3 Master pages and maybe 30 aspx files. It is a asp.net mvc project. All I have to do to get VS to freeze is type a little text or even just paste. The freezing lasts a good 5-10 seconds. My machine has 4GB of RAM and fast disks.

Could it have anything to do with asp.net mvc? Would the amount and size of other projects in the solution affect the editor?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I Solved this problem by uninstalling 'Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component' from my machine. It can be uninstalled from 'Add/Remove Programs' option in Control Panel. What a nightmare!

Now everything works just like its supposed to. I'm surprised Microsoft couldn't figure out what the problem and solution is. How much do they spend on R&D and Q/A again?????

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Thanks I'm having locking issues constantly, I hope this helps. VS is amazing at being both one of the best and worst IDE experiences.  The 'worst' seems to outweigh the 'best' most of the time unfortunately.

Comment: Have just done a fresh install of VS2008 onto a new laptop and have had this problem again! Frustrating. At least I know what the solution is now!

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue and found an [article](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/5/12/visual-studio-2008-locks-or-freezes-in-aspx.html) about the problem, rather than reinstall Office to check, I simply renamed the setup.exe to setup.exe.old and that resolved it.

Comment: The way I "fixed" the performance issues was to use the "Source Code (Text) Editor" as the default editor for .aspx, .ascx and .master

I still get intellisense inside <% %> but no html autocomplete. But its worth not having to wait 10 seconds between typing each character.

I'll try to see if my problem involves that setup.exe file and let you know.

Comment: I renamed that setup.exe file and vs is still locking up when using the default editors, it even puts the (Not Responding) in vs's title bar

Comment: In my case, this fixed the problem. I had ofice 2007 and 2010 side by side and renaming both setups was required.

Comment: Not just utterly random. Utterly bizarre. But it worked for me, too.

Comment: Worked for me too (remember to close the setup.exe that is running)

Comment: Works perfectly,thanks a lot. However how this can ever happen is really mistery.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out what the problem was with mine.  I had a protocol relative script reference in my masterpage that was reeking havick on my editor.  Hopefully a bug microsoft will fix soon.

Here is what I had:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"   
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I had to do to fix it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope that helps someone

Comment: Interesting, I use those too. I'll keep an eye out

Comment: Good spot, been annoying me for a long while +1

Comment: I was just about to give the same answer. This solved it for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that, but I guess that if you're having a lot of (probably huge) projects in the solution, this would *definitely* slow down VS for it parses the code to give you an up-to-date intellisence menu ...
Master pages are a little slow anyway, especially that VS is not that fast on rendering the HTML elements, not to mention Master pages.

Comment: Even with a huge solution 10 second freezes are not normal though.

Answer (score 1):

It can also happen if you have markup problems. 
For instance, if you have a Label control and add something like `Text="<%# TranslateLabel("lblSearch") %>"` the page will freeze even in source mode when attempting to save it. The correct sintax should be `Text='<%# TranslateLabel("lblSearch") %>'`. I know it is not your problem, but maybe it's useful for somebody else...

Answer (score 1):

With VS2005 I found the problem to be with a link to a javascript file (that was in a master page) that I entered as

```
<script src="../../js/file.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

when I change this to just `<script src="/js/file.js" ... >`

the problem went away.

NOTE while this "bad link" was in the master page, VS2005 hung even when I did not have the masterpage as an open document. Basically as soon as I tried to edit anything (or even build the app) VS hung. I had to close VS, change the offending file in note pad and open VS again. Then all was good.

The very odd thing was I added this link to the file last night and VS was still behaving ok, it was not until this morning after a restart that the file caused the problem.

I Hope this helps someone
Derek

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem off and on for a few weeks. I finally resolved it today. The source (nice pun) of the problem was source control. I am currently using Visual Source Safe 2005 (I know, I'm dumping it soon), but I think it could be an issue with any source control package.

I first suspected VSS when I was able to edit ASPX pages in the design view without issue using a machine that was not connected to VSS. If I removed source control from the project, everything worked fine.

I then discovered that somehow my VSS connection settings got changed from using a folder connection to a web connection. I'm not sure how this could have happened since I am the only one that uses VSS and I certainly didn't change it. Anyway, I reset it back and everything began to work normally again.

Comment: Disabling my svn addins didn't seem to help my problem, glad you fixed yours though

Answer (score 0):

rename worked for me i.e. changed setup.exe to setiup.exe.old

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\
  OFFICE12\Office Setup Controller\Setup.exe

wish i'd found this article first - it has taken me many man hours

thx -j

Answer (score 0):

I got the sampe problem with Visual Studio 2008 SP1. And yeah it was a masterpage as well.
The solution what I  found is to restart Visual Studio 2008 and use the source mode of ASPX file :)

I guess the problem here is a masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I removed Office 2007 to install Office 2010 beta. I have installed Office 2010 64 bits on Windows 7

I used Robert MacLean's solution, and it works for me, I just renamed the file.

Comment: Same for environment for me here. Used Robert MacLean´s solution too. Problem seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to help anybody but after trying all the answers here to no avail I deleted a huge block of commented code on my ASPX page and the behavior went away. I am not really sure why a large commented block of code would cause VS to freeze up after every edit action but that seems to be what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where Visual Studio would just hang indefinitely when opening a master page file. I solved it by opening the master page file in notepad +, removing the html, then putting it back in from visual studio.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, the uninstall of the "Visual Studio Web Authoring" program and the renaming of the Office setup.exe seem to both be related.  I watched setup.exe as I uninstalled Web Authoring and the uninstall had the side effect of removing setup.exe and all the other contents of the directory.  Also, when I had my setup.exe renamed to something else (e.g. 'setup.exe.renamed') then I had errors trying to uninstall Web Authoring.  Those errors went away when I renamed setup.exe.renamed back to setup.exe.  Anyway, just saving someone else a double effort here.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by installing this hotfix:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2008/02/09/downloadable-hotfix-performance-and-editor-fixes-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-and-visual-web-developer-express-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting ReflectedSchemas folder (C:\Documents and Settings[username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas). This folder grows quickly (mine was 2.6 GB after 4 years of programming) and by growing can slow down the VS considerably. Such as 10-20 seconds of non-responsive UI after closing an aspx or ascx file. I has not waiting them to open, I was waiting to close. Apparently the opening was easy, the closing part was the hard job!

Answer (score -1):

Uninstalling 'Visual Studio Web Authoring tool' solved this problem.